# TypeError: Cannot set property "STRING" of undefined at STRING (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have this "class":

```
function BooleanAssoc(keyNames) {
    this.assoc = {};
    $.each(keyNames, function(i, val) {
        this.assoc[val] = false;
    });
};
```

I use it like this:

```
var signUpStates = new BooleanAssoc([
    "CNPJ", 
    "PASSWORDS", 
    "ADDRESS", 
    "GENERAL_FIELDS", 
    "STATE", 
    "CITY", 
    "SEGMENT", 
    "PRODUCT",
    "EMAIL",
    "TERMS"
]);
```

I don't understand why I get a TypeError. Perhaps it's my mind that is too "pythonic". I create a dictionary ("Associative Array"), I iterate over a list of strings and create the keys and assign their values accordingly. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Try binding the callback to `$.each` to `this`: `$.each(key...(i, val){}.bind(this))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `this` is not the `this` you expect.

Try:

```
function BooleanAssoc(keyNames) {
  this.assoc = {};

  $.each(keyNames, function(i, val) {
    this.assoc[val] = false;
  }.bind(this));
};
```

ES5 environments you can just use `.forEach` too. If using ES6, you can use arrow functions which do not bind the `this` and use the parent scope:

```
function BooleanAssoc(keyNames) {
  this.assoc = {};

  keyNames.forEach(val => {
    this.assoc[val] = false;
  });
};
```

You can also do the following, although it is often considered to not be a best practice as it unnecessarily introduces variables into the scope. However, if you're in an environment like ES3, and where you cannot use shims to add ES5 features, the following will work:

```
function BooleanAssoc(keyNames) {
  var self = this;
  this.assoc = {};

  $.each(keyNames, function(i, val) {
    self.assoc[val] = false;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function BooleanAssoc(keyNames) {
    this.assoc = {};
    $.each(keyNames, function(i, val) {
        this.assoc[val] = false;
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue with the context. Inside each `this` refers to the current value not the context of the class `BooleanAssoc`.

```
function BooleanAssoc(keyNames) {
    var self = this;
    self.assoc = {};
    $.each(keyNames, function(i, val) {
        self.assoc[val] = false;
    });
};
```

Try above one instead.